# problem installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on dell laptop inspiron 15 7000 gaming

Tags: system-installation

can I install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my dell laptop inspiron 15 7000 gaming. I tried to install it using usb, but the screen is freezing when I tried Ubuntu without install.

Thanks,

Comment: What graphics chip/card are you using? Please tell us the brand name and model.

Comment: I think you need the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset` to get basic functionality of the graphics. After installation, you can install a proprietary nvidia graphics driver (into the installed system).

Comment: I just installed Linux Mint from compatibility mode. It works OK, but the system disabled my graphic driver so it consumes higher CPU. I tried to install Nividia driver, but It crushed my system. In the current mode, I can't control my screen brightness and there is no sound bar.

Comment: I found two links. Maybe this link can help, [Installing a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050ti in Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2353796). Please notice that it is about Ubuntu 16.042 LTS, so it may or may not be relevant for later versions of Ubuntu. Maybe the following link is more relevant, [How to install the NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

Answer (score 2):

I have GTX 1050 on my Yoga 720 and Ubuntu installed fine. Make sure you have the drive interface in the BIOS set to AHCI instead of RAID. I dual boot Windows 10 on my machine, here's the step I took.

Windows 10 came installed with EFI BIOS set to have secure boot enabled and drive set to RAID. Boot to Windows Safe mode, go to the BIOS and change RAID to AHCI. Windows SAFE mode will get the proper AHCI driver enabled, so the next normal boot to Window 10 should be successful.

From Windows 10 OS, I shrink the C: drive to allow 100GB of free space for Ubuntu installation. Then reboot via Ubuntu 18.04 installation USB stick. Use select to do the partition yourself, make a partition or two if you want swap in separate partition. Select your root and swap (if necessary), and nstall Ubuntu and grub2 on the partition. Under EFI installation.

Both Windows 10 and Ubuntu boot option should be available to your BIOS EFI boot selection.

Answer (score -1):

I install Ubuntu 18.04 but I have disable the GPU.

At the installation grub you have press <kbd>e</kbd> and then, after the --- put `nomodeset` and press <kbd>f10</kbd>.

The installation will work, but I can't install the nVidia drivers.